# Lock combination

Tags: java

I have some problems 
constructing a program for a combination
lock.

I want to construct a Lock
with small locks 
and assign combination to each lock

It should look like this when printed:

```
Lock Combination
1        8-4
2        1-2
3        5-3
4        10-7
5        9-6
```

Can I construct the basic code for the lock like

```
public class mainLock {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Lock" + "   " + "Combination");

        int lock = 1;

        while (lock <=5) {
            System.out.println(" "+lock);
            lock = lock+1;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that I want to
assign combination between 1-10 Random
and the number should not appear twice
as you can see in the print view.
so when you start the program it should randomly create
combination for 5 locks with 2 unique digits.

I know that for making this I probably need
to use Random or Math.random() in a way like this

```
(int)(Math.random()*10)+1
```

Think I create a class where I create a
method for the 2 different comb for each
lock

```
public class Combination {
    public int getComb() {
        int comb1, comb2;

        comb1 = (int)(Math.random()*5)+1;
        comb2 = (int)(Math.random()*5)+1;
```

to create my random numbers 
but im not sure how 
and how to assign to each lock.

help would be very appriciated!

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, tag it as such.

Comment: This has to be homework, but you have told us what you've tried and where you are stuck - well done, most people don't. You need somethign to hold the combination of each lock. So you probably need some objects to do this. So you need a Lock class you can create instances of

Comment: If an answer was helpful to you, please select it as the correct one. Otherwise, let us know why it wasn't so that we can elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You might try creating a List containing the digits, then using Collections.shuffle() to reorder it. That would give you the randomized behavior you're looking for without repeating digits. I haven't tested this, but it should work:

```
ArrayList<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    digits.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
}

Collections.shuffle(digits):
```

Then you can just read the digits out of the digits List.

Comment: Good solution for the non-repeating "random" numbers. @Jesper, when you have a problem that requires "random" numbers but applies constraints on valid values, that is a good first indication that you are not looking for a truly random number solution. (or at least as random a solution as a PRNG can provide)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as this is homework, it might not be smart to use techniques you haven't discussed in that course yet. Using only basic methods, you could try creating an array to hold each value of the combinations individually. After each time you create a random number for the combination, check it against all the values in the array. If it is unique, set it as the value for that part of the combination. If it's not unique, come up with another "random" number. This might not be the most elegant solution, but at least it uses methods at what I'm guessing are around your level of programming coursework.